# Obtener el valor de la URL Locate Dash para asignarlos a una variable, antes que se dispare el Callback

Tags: python, postgresql, plotly, dash

Buen día, estoy comenzando en Dash con Python, y requiero obtener el valor de la URL con que han llamado un programa.py, asignar ese valor a una variable y luego con ella, ejecutar un SELECT a una tabla en Postgresql. El problema radica, en que siempre se dispara primero el Callback y no me permite tomar el valor del **dcc.Location(id='path')** antes del Callback.

En este sentido, me gustaría saber si alguien está familiarizado con el tema o posee experiencia en el desarrollo de aplicaciones con DASH, Plotty.....

El código es:

```
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, Input, Output,callback
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
from pages import mmg_3
from pages import eng
import flask
app = Dash(name, use_pages=True)
def rec_enlaces(n_pos):
return enlaces[n_pos-1]
def generate_li(text_li):
a =  html.Li(children=[generate_team_a(i, j) for i, j in opclink.items()],
                  value=text_li,
                  className="mr-2",
                  id=str(text_li))
return a

def generate_team_a(text_a, n_pos):
a =  html.A(children=str(text_a),
                  href=rec_enlaces(n_pos),
                  className="mr-3",
                  id=str(text_a))
return a

PSQL_HOST=“127.0.0.1”; PSQL_PORT=“5432”; PSQL_USER=“__graph”; PSQL_PASS=mmg_3.valorumask(eng.__PALCLA); PSQL_DB=eng.__DBRMS
connection_address=“”“host=%s port=%s user=%s password=%s dbname=%s”“” % (PSQL_HOST, PSQL_PORT, PSQL_USER, PSQL_PASS, PSQL_DB)
connection = psycopg2.connect(connection_address)

#######################################################################################
Acá se necesito recuperar el URL (‘path’, ‘search’)  para extraer el NOMBRE DEL USUARIO y acceder con éste, a la tabla en Postgresql, antes que se dispare el Callback, pero siempre dispara el Callback antes y no puedo tomar el valor .the USERNAME variable. !!!
#####################################################################################
b_cur = connection.cursor()
b_cur.execute("select comg.nombre_programa, comg.descripcion 
from opc_menugraph comg, for_proggraph cfg 
where comg.nombre_programa = cfg.nombre_programa \
        **#### Aquí necesito colocar esa Variable **NOMBREUSUARIO**  que contendría el Nombre del Usuario que viene en la URL !!!!!**
        
        and nombreusuario = **NOMBREUSUARIO** \     
        and comg.cd_estatus = '001' \
        and cfg.cd_estatus = '001' order by orden_ejecucion ")

menu = {‘menu’: [‘1’]}
opclink = {}
enlaces = 
opciones = 
usuario = ‘’
indi = 1
for field in b_cur:
opclink[field[1]] = indi
enlaces.append(field[0]
opciones.append(field[1])
indi += 1
app.layout = html.Div([html.Table(style={“margin-left”: “125px”},children=[html.Tr(
children=[html.Td(children=[html.Ul(className=“nav”,children=[html.Li(children=[
html.A(href=“#”,children=[“OPCIONES DISPONIBLES”,html.Span(className=“flecha”, children=[“◥”]),],),html.Hr(),html.Ul(className=“nav”,children=[generate_li(i) for i in menu])
, ])],)]),html.Td(children=[html.Ul(className=“nav”,children=[html.Li(children=[html.A(
href=“http://127.0.0.1:8050/”,children=[“REGRESAR”],),html.Hr(),])],)]),])],),
dcc.Location(id='path'),
html.Div(id='output'),

dash.page_container
])
@app.callback(
dash.dependencies.Output(‘output’, ‘children’),
[dash.dependencies.Input(‘path’, ‘search’)])
def update_output(value):
**#######  Acá se recupera correctamente el valor de la URL, puedo obtener ese valor y podría asignarlo a la variable, pero NO me sirve ya que el callback se disparó antes y ya accedió a la tabla. !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!**

print('Request', value, '-------', flask.request.args)
usuario = value

return value

if name == ‘main’:
#app.run(debug=False, host=‘0.0.0.0’)
app.run(debug=True)
```